# Можно ли в transform: translate использовать больше 100%?

Tags: css

Условно у меня есть элемент, который нужно поднять выше другого элемента по вертикали. Можно ли писать это вот так?

```
transform: translate(-50%, -180%);
```

Comment: а почему ты решил что нельзя?

Comment: Просто везде где не гляну, используют максимум до 100. Вот и хотел уточнить

Comment: просто не попал на нужный пример. ограничения в 100% нет

Answer (score -2):

Такой подход может нести за собой другие проблемы, вёрстка может ломаться, ибо если код со временем будет меняться, то могут возникать непонятные сдвиги и возможно, множество других переломов в стилях. Значение больше 100% как минимум выглядит неадекватно, всегда, везде и во всём максимум 100%, это общепринятый стандарт. Если же тебе недостаточно, то используй другие величины -
px, em, rem, wh, wv. На замену процентам идеально подойдут пиксели - никаких границ, а выглядит так же.
Но самая лучшая комбинация которую удалось добиться мне -

```
width: 20vw;
transform: translateX(-20vw);
```

Конструкция из двух строчек очень отзывчива при сужении экрана, можно комбинировать и с другими величинами, получая интересные результаты.

Comment: Стандарт чего? Проценты - это лишь относительные величины блока. Если я хочу переместить блок на 2 ширины вправо (на 200%) - что использовать, высчитывать пиксели от этого блока с динамической шириной?) А потом блок станет шире из-за другого контента, и тогда и будет это самое "вёрстка может ломаться".